# How to Generate char sequence of dict?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want insert function for generate char-sequence, but can't write or search it.

I try use https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus-program-to-generate-a-sequence-of-n-characters-for-a-given-specific-case, but it not working for me and I get "segfault".

I have using fund with something like it, but solution above give me segfault.

```cpp
    string = salt, b_salt, outTrip, buffer;
    string dict = ".012345678A:;<=>?@BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY[\\]^_`ZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzT"
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        buffer = generateSeq(dict)
        b_salt = buffer;
        b_salt += "...";

        salt = b_salt.substr(1,2);
        s_test = crypt(buffer.c_str(), salt.c_str());

        outTrip = s_test;

        cout << seq << "\t\t\t" << outTrip << endl;
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void GenSequence(char str[], int m, int len, char *seq)
{
    int i, j=0, k, index, r;
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        if(j == 0) {
            seq[j++] = str[rand()%len];}
        else
        {
            h:
            index = rand()%len;
            for(k = 0; k < j; k++)
            {
                if(str[index] == seq[k])
                    goto h;
            }
            seq[j++] = str[index];
        }
    }
    seq[j] = '\0';
}

int main() 
{   
    int n, m, len, i;
    char str[] = {46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 65, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 90, 97, 98, 99,100,101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122};
    n = 1000;
    m = 7;
    len = strlen(str);
    string trip, match = "shi", buf, b_salt, outTrip, salt;
    char seq[m];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        outTrip = "";
        GenSequence(str, m, len, seq);
        b_salt = seq;
        b_salt += "...";

        salt = b_salt.substr(1,2);
        outTrip = crypt(seq, salt.c_str());


        cout << seq << "\t\t\t" << outTrip << endl;

    }
}
```

Solution:
I removed some wrong chars, i.e
string dict = ".0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
and it work for me.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: I added it, thanks.

Comment: The result of `strlen(str)` is undefined as `str` is not null terminated

Comment: The general idea to generate a character-sequence is as follows. First decide on a character set (that will be part of the result). Then identify a random-number-generator (positive numbers). Use the random number generator to lookup a character in the above character set. To ensure that we do not go beyond the length of the total length of the character-set use `random % char-set-length` and use the result as an index to the character set. You are likely getting a seg-fault because you are trying to access an index (generated by some random function) that is out of bounds of the character set

Comment: Ok. I guess the code has the above details. Could be as @AlanBirtles noted on the string not being null terminated.

Comment: Idk. but if add comment in string with crypt-func, then it's work, but give not result. Also, it code give me segfault after 3-4 iterations.

Comment: And I want to create an increasing sequence, not random.

Answer (score 0):

I removed some wrong chars, i.e

```
string dict = ".0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; and
```

it work for me.